Having trouble with mismatched input expecting end of line without line continuation in Tradingview
I'm having issues with a strategy I am trying to create. I've tried manually to ensure that 4 spaces are right as they should be starting at line bb_position. I have the code ready to be pasted and in the correct format, it is when I do so, it has each line cascading to the right further and further. I am on mobile as I don't have access to a PC currently and editing it while in the pine editor is a nightmare as the cursor jumps around, randomly highlights code and various other things except do what i want it to. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code.
//@version=5
strategy("Too EZ", overlay=true, initial_capital=100000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100)

// Parameters
length = input.int(20, "Length")
bb_std = input.float(2.0, "Bollinger Bands Standard Deviation")
rsi_oversold = input.int(25, "RSI Oversold")
rsi_overbought = input.int(75, "RSI Overbought")
z_score_threshold = input.float(2.0, "Z-Score Threshold")
stoch_length = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length")
stoch_smooth = input.int(3, "Stochastic Smooth")
williams_length = input.int(14, "Williams %R Length")

// Weights
bb_weight = input.float(1.0, "Bollinger Bands Weight", minval=0.0, maxval=5.0, step=0.1)
rsi_weight = input.float(1.0, "RSI Weight", minval=0.0, maxval=5.0, step=0.1)
z_score_weight = input.float(1.0, "Z-Score Weight", minval=0.0, maxval=5.0, step=0.1)
stoch_weight = input.float(1.0, "Stochastic Weight", minval=0.0, maxval=5.0, step=0.1)
williams_weight = input.float(1.0, "Williams %R Weight", minval=0.0, maxval=5.0, step=0.1)

// Other inputs
upper_threshold = input.float(0.9, "Upper Threshold", minval=0.0, maxval=1.0, step=0.01)
lower_threshold = input.float(-0.9, "Lower Threshold", minval=-1.0, maxval=0.0, step=0.01)
use_trend_filter = input.bool(true, "Use Trend Filter")
trend_ma_length = input.int(200, "Trend MA Length")

// Strategy-specific inputs
stop_loss_percent = input.float(0.75, "Stop Loss %", minval=0.1, maxval=10, step=0.01)
take_profit_percent = input.float(1.4, "Take Profit %", minval=0.1, maxval=10, step=0.01)

var float middle = na
var float upper = na
var float lower = na
middle, upper, lower := ta.bb(close, length, bb_std)

calc_signals() =>
    // 1. Bollinger Bands
    bb_position = ((close - lower) / (upper - lower)) * 2 - 1

    // 2. RSI
    rsi = ta.rsi(close, length)
    rsi_normalized = (rsi - 50) / 50

    // 3. Z-Score
    z_score = (close - ta.sma(close, length)) / ta.stdev(close, length)
    z_score_normalized = math.max(math.min(z_score / z_score_threshold, 1), -1)

    // 4. Stochastic Oscillator
    stoch_k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, stoch_length), stoch_smooth)
    stoch_normalized = (stoch_k - 50) / 50

    // 5. Williams %R
    williams = ta.wpr(williams_length)
    williams_normalized = (williams + 50) / 50

    // Composite Signal with weights
    total_weight = bb_weight + rsi_weight + z_score_weight + stoch_weight + williams_weight
    weighted_bb = bb_position * bb_weight
    weighted_rsi = rsi_normalized * rsi_weight
    weighted_z_score = z_score_normalized * z_score_weight
    weighted_stoch = stoch_normalized * stoch_weight
    weighted_williams = williams_normalized * williams_weight
    composite_signal = (weighted_bb + weighted_rsi + weighted_z_score + weighted_stoch + weighted_williams) / total_weight
    composite_signal := math.max(math.min(composite_signal, 1), -1)  // Ensure range is -1 to 1

    // Trend MA (RMA only)
    trend_ma = ta.rma(close, trend_ma_length)

    // Entry signals
    long_entry = ta.crossover(composite_signal, lower_threshold)
    short_entry = ta.crossunder(composite_signal, upper_threshold)

    // Apply trend filter if enabled
    long_entry := use_trend_filter ? (long_entry and close > trend_ma) : long_entry
    short_entry := use_trend_filter ? (short_entry and close < trend_ma) : short_entry

    [long_entry, short_entry, composite_signal, trend_ma]

[long_signal, short_signal, composite_signal, trend_ma] = calc_signals()

// Strategy execution
if (long_signal)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (short_signal)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Calculate stop loss and take profit prices
long_sl = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stop_loss_percent / 100)
long_tp = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + take_profit_percent / 100)
short_sl = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stop_loss_percent / 100)
short_tp = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - take_profit_percent / 100)

// Exit trades
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", "Long", stop=long_sl, limit=long_tp)
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short", "Short", stop=short_sl, limit=short_tp)

// Force close positions if signal reverses
if (strategy.position_size > 0 and short_signal)
    strategy.close("Long")
if (strategy.position_size < 0 and long_signal)
    strategy.close("Short")

I've tried manually ensuring the indentation is correct to no avail as trying to work within the pine editor on mobile is troublesome at best.
